# copy site collection in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, solution, sitecollection, spsite

I would like to be able to copy the entire site collection http://server.ltd/sites/ABC  to http://server.ltd/sites/DEF

is there any easy solution, because I tried to Save as template at the site level then tried to upload the solution to the newly created site collection but it failed.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: Using stsadm command, you can able to copy entire site collection and then you go for restoring to destinatioin. Open cmd, then navigate stsadm.exe location till c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extentions\14\bin then type stsadm, this will give update that stsadm working or not, m cIf u found the list of stsadm command. Then type stsadm -help backup, tihs will give guidence to use stsadm -backkup and

Answer (score 2):

You can use powershell for that:

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity http://server.ltd/sites/ABC -Path c:\temp\abc.bak
```

and then restore with:

```
Restore-SPSite http://server.ltd/sites/DEF -Path c:\temp\abc.bak
```

Make sure you check the available options like preserving security information, versioning, etc:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617(v=office.14).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx

Comment: Hi @Luis I tried this. When I try to visit the new site collection, it says 'Website declined to show this webpage' with status code 403.

Comment: @a_rahmanshah its forbidden, goto central admin -> site collection admin and add your user account

Comment: Hi @Luis, in SP2010 there is no option to preserve security information, versioning etc, so your suggestions are not applicable.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, applicable to what? The OP did not mention security information.

Comment: You wrote: "Make sure you check the available options like preserving security information, versioning". In SharePoint2010 you don't have this options available, so your suggestion is not applicable for SP2010.

Answer (score 0):

you can backup sitecollection with powershell and restore it again in new path ,
[this](http://www.bradleyschacht.com/backup-and-restore-sharepoint-2010-site-collection-with-powershell/) link could help you.